# Using cloneCollection in MongoDB: how to authenticate?

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to clone a remotely hosted collection to my local Mongo database. I tried opening up the mongo console in the local environment and issued:

```
db.runCommand({cloneCollection: "<dbname.colname>", from: "<remotehost:port>"})
```

It fails with

```
"errmsg" : "exception: nextSafe(): { $err: \"not authorized for query on <dbname>.system.namespaces\", code: 16550 }",
"code" : 13106,
```

How do I properly authorize with the remote server to clone the collection?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately that's currently not possible. There is a [Jira ticket](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-2931) open for this feature. As a workaround you could consider using `mongodump --collection` and `mongorestore`.

Comment: Thanks! I ended up using mongoexport and mongoimport to clone the collections.

Comment: That's a viable option too, although keep in mind that mongodump produces BSON output which preserves the richer type information of BSON more accurately than mongoexport, which produces JSON output.