# CloneCollection in Mongodb

Tags: mongodb, collections, clone

I am having authenticated mongodb, and I need to clone collection with particular query to run a job. 
Before authentication enabled I am able to clone collection from remote host .
db.runCommand({ cloneCollection: "namespace", from: "remoteHost", query: {}})

But after enable authentication It is not possible to clone collection. Is there any alternative to this, I don't want to dump and restore.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using cloneCollection in MongoDB: how to authenticate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21958211/using-clonecollection-in-mongodb-how-to-authenticate)

Comment: Thanks Felix for response, it means no alternative other that mongodump and restore.

Comment: for the moment yes...

Comment: Okay.. I am asking it in other way, is it possible to perform aggregation through javascript to secondary node, then store that result to variable and insert that stored data in mu localdatabase to create an new collection with that aggregated data